# calculate two fields to a new unbound in crystal report with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

There are three columns in my data grid control. `X1= Debits`, `X2= Credits` and `X3= Available Balance` (like a bank balance statement). The X1 & X2 receive the data's from database & X3 calculate the amount by the following code:

```
 Dim rCount As Integer
 rCount = ds1.Tables(0).Rows.Count
 With DG_All
            For x As Integer = 0 To rCount - 1
                .Rows.Add()
                .Rows(x).Cells(0).Value = ds1.Tables(0).Rows(x)(0) 'X1
                .Rows(x).Cells(1).Value = ds1.Tables(0).Rows(x)(1) 'X2

                If x = 0 Then 'If first row of grid
                    If .Rows(x).Cells(0).Value = 0 Then 'If X1=0 & X2<0
                        .Rows(x).Cells(2).Value = .Rows(x).Cells(1).Value
                    Else 'If X1<0 & X2=0
                        .Rows(x).Cells(2).Value = .Rows(x).Cells(0).Value
                    End If
                Else  'If the grid has more then 1 rows
                    If .Rows(x).Cells(0).Value = 0 Then
                        .Rows(x).Cells(2).Value = .Rows(x - 1).Cells(2).Value + .Rows(x).Cells(1).Value
                    Else
                        .Rows(x).Cells(2).Value = .Rows(x - 1).Cells(2).Value - .Rows(x).Cells(0).Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next
 End With
```

My question is, I need to use this calculation method in crystal report to populate the available balance field in a new column.

Please can anyone help me?

I am using VB.Net 2012 Ultimate

Comment: you need the syntax for the formula in crystal reports?

Comment: of course. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

giving you the basic idea, change as per your fields and requrirement.

```
Local Numbervar rCount:="Take your rows count here";
Local Numbervar x;
Local Numbervar x1;
Local Numbervar x2;

            For x := 0 To rCount - 1 Do
(
                X1= "field from databaset" 'X1
                X2= "field from databaset" 'X2

Write your If and Else if confitions here
)
```

Note: I would have written but don't know what is row value and other terms from your code

Comment: I found the answer. But the method is different.Thank you for spent your valuable time for me.